# How do I save a timer's interval everytime my form closes?Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Well, I had a hard time doing this but I am sure it is something related to settings I just need to know the codes and what kind of setting it needs to be like if it is a boolean,string,etc. Thanks

Comment: Show what you've tried and a specific example of where your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, here it is:

go to properties of your form then go to settings then make it integer
codes:

```
My.Settings."name" = Timer1.Interval
Timer1.Enabled = True

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```